# Ubuntu lts display is zoomed/scaled after changing dell screen

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, display, screen, flicker

I used to have screen flickering problem and it became frequent. When I visited the service center they said it is the screen problem and changed the screen in 1 day. Next day when I booted into ubuntu with the new screen, the display was scaled positively i.e, fullscreen is visible but the icons and buttons are of bigger size. All applications including the browser, terminal are scaled. When I booted to windows all icons were of normal size.

I also checked the zoom level in Universal access setting, it was off. I tried various options in settings but it didn't solve the problem.

What might be the reason? Any solution?

I am attaching an ss of my new terminal size. You might know the default terminal size of ubuntu if you have used it regularly

[image: ss of my scaled screen]

Comment: Do you just need to turn up your resolution?

Comment: @MarkKirby maybe yes but I dont see any options for that. I tried all of the resolutions present in display settings but they didn't change. Did I get a wrong screen attached? But my windows screen seems fine with all icons on same size

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this.
I need to change the screen with the original resolution!
This is the problem of the new screen's resolution. My desktop model originally has 1920×1080 pixels but the service man had put a new screen with 1366×768 pixels which means I almost lost half of the pixels I originally had.

**Helpful note while changing desktop screens:**
There might be a scam/mistake done by the service man because more the resolution, more the screen price. Hence, we need to keep in mind the resolution of screen whenever it is changed.